java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$Serialization | Delta IO | eks sparkOperator
I am trying to run the spark job which reads the data from delta lake which is residing in s3 with sparkOperator manifest which is running on eks.
I am able to run the job using docker run once i build the docker image using CMD[spark-submit , test.py] , but when i execute same with spark operator its throwing below error.

I am able to read the data that is in s3 with format as parquet but when I specify the read format as delta and the data is in delta format only. spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://bucket/path") 

Driver stacktrace:

24/04/19 17:34:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: toString at <unknown>:0, took 1.043403 s
24/04/19 17:34:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on 10.0.2.24, 
    executor 1: java.lang.ClassCastException 
    (cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy 
    to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance.arguments of type scala.collection.Seq 
    in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance) [duplicate 7]
24/04/19 17:34:02 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    zoning = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://my-s3bucketname/rootfolder/delta_load_tyler")
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 204, in load
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.load.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) (10.0.2.24 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance.arguments of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:464)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.toBaseRelation(DeltaTableV2.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:305)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

